# using url::to() in main.php file

Tags: yii, yii2

in my `main.php` i have this code

```
  'authClientCollection' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
            'clients' => [

                'google' => [
                    'class' => 'Da\User\AuthClient\Google', 
                    'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxapps.googleusercontent.com',
                    'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'returnUrl' => Url::to(['user/security/auth', 'authclient' => 'google']], true),
                ],
```

but i get this error.

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'controller' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseUrl.php on line 136
```

i also tried `\Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('user/security/auth', ['authclient' => 'google']),`

and got this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'urlManager' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\frontend\config\main.php on line 160
```

how do i set an absolute url in my main.php? thanks

Comment: You can't use `Url::to()` or `Yii::$app` in config file. Config files are processed even before application instance is created, because configuration is needed to create that instance. You should simply hardcode the url. If you absolutely need to set the url dynamicaly using url manager, you should set it in some event after the application instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `returnUrl` or other component configurations in `on beforeRequest` section in `main.php`

```
'components' => [
    'google' => [
        'class' => 'Da\User\AuthClient\Google',
        'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxapps.googleusercontent.com',
        'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ],
],
'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
    Yii::$app->google->returnUrl = Url::to(['user/security/auth', 'authclient' => 'google'], true);
},
```

[Ref Link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications#application-events)

- You can deal with database also

Comment: i'm getting a `Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::google`

Comment: are you sure  'google' added into 'components' ?

Comment: yes, its in the `'components' => [  'authClientCollection' => [  'clients' => [  'google' => [  ....  ]  ] ] ]`

Comment: Try This > Yii::$app->authClientCollection->clients->google->returnUrl = Url::to()....